The Tower of (-----)
What's the name of this tower?
As usual, explain your reasoning. (You'll know if your answer is correct).



I changed the title and the question in the body. Don't get mislead by the title though, this isn't a famous tower.

This is the tower of

 MORSE!

Why?

 Basically the rectangles represent dashes and the circles represent dots in MORSE CODE. The colors show how dots and dashes are to be grouped. So from the center or (‘top’) you have 2xRed Rectangles, 3xYellow Rectangles, 1xBlue Circle then Rectangle then Circle, 3xGrey circles and 1xGreen circles resulting in: _ _ / _ _ _ / ._. / … / .
 which decodes as MORSE!

The title:

 Subtly hints at the dashes whilst simultaneously enumerating the length of the answer (5) with the (- - - - -).

